# Disabled scheduled agent ran for some reason on the indicated server

Tags: lotus-notes, agent

Earlier today, a disabled scheduled agent ran on the indicated server where it would run. Note that the actual agent design element resides in a different server, also, the date where it would run is not specified.

It's function is to send an email to specific users. Upon checking the email, the sender some colleague (but the last modification date of the agent is way back 2014).

I'd like to ask if there's any way that a disabled agent would run without actually enabling it?

Also, is there a way where I can see who triggered the agent? I checked in the "Agent -> Log" but it did not indicated who ran the agent.

I also checked in the log.nsf (where the agent resides) but log is not there. I can't check in the indicated server where the agent ran because it's no longer existing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least four ways to run an agent that come to my mind, and there for sure are more:

1. You can run every agent just with a right- click in the designer and then "Run".
2. You can run an agent with Formula code:

   @Command([ToolsRunMacro] ; "NameOfYourAgent" )
   @Command([RunAgent] ; "NameOfYourAgent" )
3. Or with LotusScript- Code:

   Set agent = db.GetAgent( "NameOfYourAgent" )
   Call agent.Run()
   '- or
   Call agent.RunOnServer()
4. You can run it using a server console command:

   tell amgr run "path\nameofyourdatabase.nsf" 'NameOfYourAgent'

(double quotes and single quote has to be mixed for this)...

So: just that an agent is disabled does not mean it cannot be run...

Comment: Thanks @torsten, big help